# When I solve 1st linear ODE with p(t) jump discontinuous, why should I find continuous y?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

> Solve the initial value problem.
> $$\frac{dy}{dt}+p(t)y=0, y\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$$
> $$\text{where}\qquad p(t)=
> \begin{cases}
> \sin(t),  & 0 \le t \le \pi \\
> \cos(t), & \pi < t
> \end{cases}$$

My textbook said:

> Discontinuous Coefficients. Linear differential equations sometimes occur in which one or both of the functions p and g have jump discontinuities. If $t_0$ is such a point of discontinuity, then it is necessary to solve the equation separately for $t < t_0$ and $t > t_0$. Afterward, the two solutions are matched so that y is continuous at $t_0$; this is accomplished by a proper choice of the arbitrary constants. The following two problems illustrate this situation. Note in each case that it is impossible also to make $y'$ continuous at $t_0$.

And I obtained the solution to the above initial value problem:
$$y(t) = e^{cos(t)} (0 \le t \le \pi)\text{ (using $y(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 1$)}$$
$$ke^{-\sin(t)} (\pi < t) \text{ (k is an arbitrary constant)}$$

In this case, why should I find the particular value of $k$ such that $e^{\cos(\pi)} = ke^{-\sin(\pi)}$?
I think $k$ should remain as an arbitrary constant because there is no mention that $y$ should be continuous. Is it desirable to find continuous $y(t)$ although there is no mention that $y$ should be continuous? If so, why?